# Set dynamic ValueConverter-Parameter for ValueConverter applied by style

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding, ivalueconverter

I'm having a ui with multiple buttons that change on a click event. For not having to change every button with it's own logic, I applied multiple IValueConverters and gave them the buttons name as a string.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <converters:ButtonVisibilityConverter x:Key="ButtonVisibilityConverter" />
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
...

<Button x:Name="MyData" ... 
  FontSize="{Binding ActiveButton, Converter={StaticResource ButtonVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=MyData}" />
```

ActiveButton is a string that keeps the name of the currently focused button. Each button got such a unique name (in this case `MyData`).

The converter compares the values of `ActiveButton` and `MyData`, and returns the corresponding values.

Now what I want is that I can use styles for the buttons that I don't have to write each value converter for each button, because they differ only in the ID (e.g. `MyData`, `Settings`).

I tried the following approach:

```
<Style x:Key="ConvertersStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" 
        Value="{Binding ActiveButton, Converter={StaticResource ButtonFontSizeConverter}, ConverterParameter=???}"/>
                ...
</Style>

...

<Button ... Style="{StaticResource ConvertersStyle}" />
```

But I found no option to make the `ConverterParameter` dynamically get the buttons `x:Name` or another identifier.

Is there a way to get the name of the button or e.g. give the style a parameter?

Comment: What you should do is apply a value converter on the style property of the button then on the basis of the change in property change the style!

Comment: Could you explain that more in detail? I'm not really understanding what you mean

Comment: Why not record the currently focused button with a property and handle the logic in the click event? I mean  you can compare the button you clicked with the record button in the click event to check if they are the same button and then handle logic.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing exactly this with the `ActiveButton` property. My problem is just that I want to call the ValueConverter with a dynamic parameter that tells it which button it currently works on.

Comment: When you click the button, you should know which button you are clicking.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the ValueConverter doesn't. Unfortunately it got no default reference to the control it's applied to. I could give it the reference as a parameter maybe, but I couldn't find out how to do that, if I apply it by style or another dynamic way.